# Understanding how to construct an Infinitival Relative Clause

Tags: relative-clauses

> 1. The best place **from which** **to** set out is Aberdin (Pullum) - **correct**

> 2. There is one wood in the entire town **in which to** find wood peckers - **wrong**

> 3. Jellyfish tentacles are barbed venomous stingers **not to be touched** -  **wrong**

> 4. That’s a magnificent waterfall spot **at which** **to** have a good time. - **wrong**

> 5. This year Antarctica saw the **highest** ever temperature to have been recorded by researchers. - **???**

The basic principle I used in constructing the sentences (2-5 ) is identical to the one in Pullum's example. (wh-type/ non-wh, guess, doesn't make any difference).

Why the 1st sentence is correct and the others, built on the same principle, are not?

Is Infinitival RC used in Superlative constructions only?

How about

> This is one of the problems to be solved.

> Here’s a very interesting item for you to read (+for)

Would very much appreciate any help, because I am so much confused.

Comment: Your sentences are not grammatically wrong, they just sound odd. (No. 5 is correct except that it should be _recorded_.) (2) sounds as though the purpose of the wood is to house woodpeckers - it would be more natural to say _in which you can find_ them. (3) sounds as though there is a rule about touching jellyfish tentacles, rather than that it's advisable not to!

Comment: The syntax of Infinitival relatives is quite tricky. Are you sure you have reached a suitable level in your studies to be able to grasp it? The composition of your question suggests that you haven't.